# Node count of a graph not matching

Tags: python, mongodb, social-networking, data-visualization, networkx

I have a MDB database with the following attributes about forum posts:

```
thread
author (posted in the thread)
children (a list of authors who replied to the post)
child_count (number of children in the list)
```

Im trying to build a graph with the following nodes:

```
thread
author
child authors
```

the total distinct authors in my database are more than 30,000 but the graph that is generated the author count is around 3000. Or, out of a total of 33000 nodes, the following code generates around 5000. What is going on here?

```
for doc in coll.find():

    thread = doc['thread'].encode('utf-8')
    author_parent = doc['author'].encode('utf-8')
    children = doc['children']
    children_count = len(children)
    #print G.nodes()

    #print post_parent, author, doc['thread']
    try:
        if thread in G:
            continue
        else:
            G.add_node(thread, color='red')
            thread_count+=1


        if author_parent in G:
            G.add_edge(author_parent, thread)
        else:
            G.add_node(author_parent, color='green')
            G.add_edge(author_parent, thread, weight=0)
            author_count+=1


        if doc['child_count']!=0:          
            for doc in children:
                if doc['author'].encode("utf-8") in G:
                    print doc['author'].encode("utf-8"), 'in G'
                    G.add_edge(doc['author'].encode("utf-8"), author_parent)
                else:
                    G.add_node(doc['author'].encode("utf-8"),color='green')
                    G.add_edge(doc['author'].encode("utf-8"), author_parent, weight=0)
                    author_count+=1     

    except:
        print "failed"
        nx.write_dot(G,PATH)

    print thread_count, author_count, children_count
```

Comment: Are you sure that `coll.find()` returns 30000 results?

Comment: @brice coll.find() returns more than 500,000 results. Distinct authors are around 30,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. The continue statement was skipping to the next iteration so I was losing many nodes that way.